# Check for null in case

Tags: sql, oracle

I had a task to check if field contains null and if it does i have to change it to 0 and then sum.

**This is how table looks**

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                           DATE
 SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                               NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)
```

I had to sum fields SAL and COMM

So i created this SQL code.

```
select ename, NVL(sal,0)+NVL(comm,0) money from emp;
```

**And it outputted everything right**

```
ENAME           MONEY
---------- ----------
SMITH             800
ALLEN            1900
WARD             1750
JONES            2975
MARTIN           2650
BLAKE            2850
CLARK            2450
SCOTT            3000
KING             5000
TURNER           1500
ADAMS            1100

ENAME           MONEY
---------- ----------
JAMES             950
FORD             3000
MILLER           1300
```

But now i have to do the same using **CASE** statement.
But i seem to fail everything i try, maybe its because i have not understood how case works in SQL as good.

**Code that i tried**

```
select ename, 
case 
when comm is null then sal+0
when sal is null then comm+0
end nauda
from emp;
```

**And it outputted this**

```
ENAME           MONEY
---------- ----------
SMITH             800
ALLEN
WARD
JONES            2975
MARTIN
BLAKE            2850
CLARK            2450
SCOTT            3000
KING             5000
TURNER
ADAMS            1100

ENAME           MONEY
---------- ----------
JAMES             950
FORD             3000
MILLER           1300
```

Comment: Not `in null`, `is null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `coalesce()` to `nvl()` because it is ANSI standard:

```
select ename, coalesce(sal, 0) + coalesce(comm, 0) as money
from emp;
```

This is the right way to solve your problem.  But, if you wanted to use `case`, here is one way:

```
select ename,
       (case when sal is not null and comm is not null then sal + comm
             when sal is not null then sal
             when comm is not null then comm
             else 0
        end) as money
from emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a subquery, this way you can manipulate data in all kinds of ways. Can also help to do things on smaller datasets.

```
select
  ename,
  comm,
  sal
from
 (select 
    ename, 
    nvl(com, 0) as comm,
    nvl(sal, 0) as sal
  from 
    emp)
```